# Classification Algorithm for Segmented Regression Time Series

Tags: classification, regression

I have Segmented Linear Regression dataset in JSON format like this:

```
var series = [
    {x:0,w:10,m:0.5,b:50},
    {x:10,w:5,m:0.6,b:40},
    {x:15,w:20,m:1,b:100},
    // So on....
];
```

the Dataset formatted for typical line equation: **y=mx+b**
Here is a JSFiddle link that describes the situation with canvas element: https://jsfiddle.net/digerkam/7krb50z8/

My problem is that classifying/grouping the similar segments like the yellow one:

[image: processes]

I tried many things, I researched eveywhere I found, I thought so many times but no luck to find the alghorithm, or any equation for detect continuity/similarity...

Espacially detecting changes between A and B is so confusing my mind, because it has very similar characteristic like noizes in C part.

So how can classify this dataset as expected? Which alghorithm can solve this mystery? Thank you!